# how to run test cases parallely using selenium + testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I wanted to run test cases parallely with different parameters . My testng.xml would look like this

```
   <suite name="Automation Testing" preserve-order="true">

      <parameter name="browser" value="@BROWSER@"/> 

        <test name="Login">
          <classes>
             <class name="common.Login" > </class> 
          </classes>     
        </test>     

     </suite>
```

Java Class which accept parameters

```
    @parameters({'browser'})
    @beforesuite
    public void login(String browser){
    if(broswer.equals('ff')){
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() 
    }  
    }
```

I have gone through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625256/how-to-run-the-test-in-parallel-using-selenium-webdrivertestng ... But i have not anything out it ... please let me know how i can do it .....

Comment: why don't you put parallel="tests" in your testng.xml

Comment: where are you going to pass @browser@ from?

Comment: @pArAs ya , but i wanted to run with different parameters . lets say, for the 1st instance it should invoke ff browser , for second instance it should invoke chrome browser .

Comment: i am getting values(inputs) from user(cmd) through ANT. from testng.xml i will pass these parameters to login.java using @parameters annotation.

Comment: then you can put Parameter tag in every Test of testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same testcase to be run on different browsers, there are different ways.

1. Define multiple `<test>` in our xml file and have individual parameters.  You would need to have a new name for each @BROWSER@ i.e. @BROWSER1, @BROWSER2.  Then run with parallel = tests which would trigger the same testcases on different browsers.  However, the issue with this approach is you will have to always supply fixed number of browses to your ant xml
2. Another approach can be, to supply a comma separated list to your @BROWSER@  parameter.  Use a dataprovider to do a split and create driver instances.  Set parallel= methods.
3. Set parallel= methods.  Control browser based paralle runs from outside i.e Trigger various builds if you are using something like Jenkins with different parameter values for @BROWSER@